# MySQL connector/python ImportError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, python3

I'm very new to Ubuntu/Linux and Python so it's entirely possible I'm missing something obvious here. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, server version.

I've just installed the official MySQL connector/python (2.1.7, python3 version) using `dpkg -i [package-name].deb` (obviously I replaced `[package-name]` with the actual name). It's listed as being compatible with Python 3.5, which is the version I have. When I try to verify the installation through the Python interpreter using `import mysql.connector`, I just get the following error:

```
 >>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

On one similar question, I've seen it suggested that the connector may not have installed properly if python is not in the path. I didn't seem to get any issues during the installation; the file python3 is in `/usr/bin` which is definitely in the path, but seems to be a link to the file python3.5 in the same location. Running the command `which python3` gives the output `usr/bin/python3` but running `which python` gives no output.

The package apparently also contained a C library, which seems to have installed in `usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. Nothing else in that directory is called anything related to MySQL.

What should I be looking for to know whether it's an issue with the connector installation or with Python itself? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is to install corresponding Python 3 module:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector
```

It fixes `import mysql.connector` error:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

---

And similar for Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector

$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That seems to require Python 2.6 or 2.7:
`You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-connector-python-cext : Depends: python2.6 but it is not installable or
                                        python2.7 but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: python (>= 2.6.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: I do not understand where you got problems. On clean installation both Python 2 and 3 modules are installed successfully. Do you have any PPAs added? Did you tried `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get -f install` then re-running the command you first suggested seems to have worked for me, thank you! As a side note, I have one PPA added but that one doesn't seem to contain anything directly related to this issue.